# Ubuntu Network: Allow UDP connection to Port B if a UDP connection was established to Port A before

Tags: ubuntu, networking, firewall, udp, whitelist

**I want to setup an IPv4 firewall for UDP connections to port :7777 with the following rules:**

- By default block all connections to UDP Port :7777.
- Allow only whitelisted IPs connections to UDP Port :7777.
- If an IP has made a UDP connection to port :8888 then add it to the whitelist.

**How can I archive this?** Can this be done using IPTables, UFW or something else?

Comment: What do you mean by UDP connection? I assume you'd want some rules on 8888, otherwise anyone could simply send a packet and establish a "connection", allowing them access to 7777 - but at that point, why not just put the rules on 7777 and cut out the middle?